# How to hijack the String.class

Tags: java

So basically I just want to debug a couple of simple scripts by trying a new method, I have been successful in the past by hooking the URL.class (using the source from the jdk and recompling), however I realized that how can I print out a string, before it is even a string?

I want to be able to write to file, or print out, any string that goes through the string class, but how can I create a pipe method when I am within the string class itself?

I.e. a char array is being passed into the string, how do I grab that, make it a string and send it to the print out command from within the string class? If I am too vague I will provide some examples.

Comment: If you really wanna do that couldn't you add this line as the last line of each constructor in the String class? System.out.println(this.toString());

Comment: Oh my god, I didnt even think of something that simple, I was trying to pipe each output through its own method, I'm going to try this in a second. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this is too simple, but System.out.print(char c) over and over on the characters in your fake String class?  You can always print primitive values.

Comment: it looks like it was answered above, but you can also 1) just put a break point there and use a debugger or 2) replace the java.lang.String class by specifying your own using the -Xbootclasspath non-standard java option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it is a really bad idea to tweak the implementations of Java standard classes, even if you are only doing it to try and debug something.  The problem is that you can break things really badly.

For instance, @Roflcoptr suggests that you add a `System.out.println(...)` to each `String` constructor.  But what would happen if the `PrintStream.println` call tried to construct a String for some reason?  And what would happen during JVM bootstrapping if something tried to construct a String ... before the `System.*` stream objects were initialized?

I'm not saying it won't work. I'm not saying you can't make it work.  I'm *am* saying that hackery like this is liable to fail in spectacular and horrible ways.

My advice would be to find another way to debug / diagnose your problem.  For example, set a breakpoint on the relevant String constructor.

Comment: Both problems are easily solvable: 1. If `println` really did it, you can use a ThreadLocal or StackTrace inspection to avoid infinite recursion. 2. Use a global variable set when your program begins to avoid getting problems during the bootstrap. That said, I fully agree with your advice.

Comment: Stack trace capture is likely create strings under some circumstances.  Using threadlocals or a global may change the class dependencies, resulting in a different class load / initialization order during bootstrap ... and break other things.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to recompiling from the JDK source might be to use [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), which allows you to add or replace behavior to previously compiled classes. [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) is one tool supporting aspect-oriented programming for Java.

Comment: AOP sucks. AOP is for general problems, you cant use it for something like String, your asking for real trouble. Yours system would become unbearably slow if everytime a String was used/constructed an interceptor ran. And what would the interceptor do ? print something which means another string is created...

Comment: This question is about *debugging*, in which slower behavior is expected. Your personal antipathy toward AOP in production systems is not relevant. The presumption that the tracing would create a new string is not necessarily true.